# from Windows 10 to Ubuntu issues

Tags: boot, system-installation, wubi

Good evening,
I confess, I'm a begineer. I've just heard about Linux and wanted to try it on my just turned Windows 10 PC.

1. wubi and Windows 10

Yet, I met a first issue with wubi which told me that the Ubuntu 14.04.3 installer cannot download the metalink and therefore the issue. It also gave me a reference to a log file I don't know how to reach!
c:\users\antoine\appdata\local\temp\wubi-14.04-rev286.log
I am aware that having windows 10 may prevent me to use wubi.
The second issue I met was when I tried to install it manually.

2. Live CD

After having downloaded ubuntu on a CD, I accessed to the boot interface in order to change the booting. After removing the safe-I-don't-know-what I only had three choices of booting
IVP4
IVP6
Windows
No Cd booting.

3. Live key

I also have a liveLinux key a friend of mine gave me to help me instal Linux

My questions are:
Is there any chance to boot to my CD in order to really install Linux on my device?
Is there any way I can install Ubuntu thanks to the wubi?
How can install Linux thanks to this key that doesn't have any .iso file?

Thanks for considering my worries!

Comment: Wubi probably won't work with Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a newbie and want to try out Ubuntu before making any changes to your Windows you can try Ubuntu in VMware as a virtual box, many users are running into issues with windows 10 and ubuntu, ideally there should be no problem if done with understanding, if you have important files please back them, make sure you know your windows 8.1/7 key before making any changes. sometimes both systems get unusable, this forum is getting full of question of windows 10 and Ubuntu issue, read some of the and try to figure what you can avoid before you make unalterable changes. Read the article https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
I think you should be good.